# how to use cloud web security scanner in gcp if the login details are complex

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform

I want to scan my app which is in GCP using cloud web security scanner and we are using more than two fields for login page , like client id , username and password but as per google document we have to pass two input username and password , so there anyway we can scan it without failed scan.

note :- we are not using IAP authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to suggest you to [raise a Feature Request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#:%7E:text=Create%20new%20Web%20Security%20Scanner%20issue) to make the Web Security Scanner more adaptative to your needs.

Besides, you could gather the additional fields from the URL itself (from the GET request) to automatically populate the missing field.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion , I will raise a feature request.